# Facebook Timeline display bug

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I'm getting a really weird display bug in Facebook Timeline, that renders the interface pretty much unusable.

### Screenshots

[One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlmD8.png), [two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyhJc.png)

### Questions

- Has anyone seen this precise bug?
- Generally, when confronted with such a bug, what is the best strategy?

### Tried

- Hard refresh
- Flush cache
- Checking for 404s on eg CSS files
- Inspecting some elements: some elements have weird HTML-embedded styles

Comment: Is just on the Pages, or is every single page like this?

Comment: You can report it [here](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=297365590303574).

Comment: @fogest All timelines (seen people and pages)

Comment: Try a different browser.

Comment: Yes, weirdly, Chromium does not exhibit the issue.

Comment: This happened to me before but it was due to a lousy connection I had. The very same thing: then the browser would check back and as the server said "not modified", the browser would load the corrupted page again. However, having this on a specific browser discards my suspicions.

Comment: Facebook devs forgot to check compatibility on Chromium ;)

Answer (score 1):

The only other strategies would be to use

- a different browser
- a new IP
- a new internet connection

As Alex said, the recommended way would be to report it http://www.facebook.com/help/contact_us.php?id=297365590303574